# Flutter : Rebuild widget asynchrone with Provider, setState() or markNeedsBuild called during build

Tags: flutter, asynchronous, build, provider, rebuild

I have a problem with asynchrone in my piano app with flutter. It needs to play notes and change color on the keys when I call context.read().playNoteFromIndex(noteIndex, midiNote).

So, each time I call the playNoteFromIndex, the color of the key changes.

Here's the PianoKeyProvider :

Future playNoteFromIndex(int index, int midi) async {
_colorList![index] = Colors.blue;

```
      notifyListeners();

      _flutterMidi.playMidiNote(midi: midi);

      await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 500));

      _colorList![index] = Colors.white;

      notifyListeners();
  }
```

In the build widget, I have a consumer that rebuild widgets when the color change :
Flexible(
flex: 1,
child: Consumer(
builder: (context, pianoKeysProvider, child) {
return ListView.builder(
itemCount: 7,
scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
controller: ScrollController(initialScrollOffset: 1500.0),
itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
final int i = index * 12;
return SafeArea(
child: Stack(
children: [
Row(
mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
children: [
_buildKey(24 + i, false, context, i),
_buildKey(26 + i, false, context, i + 2),
_buildKey(28 + i, false, context, i + 4),
_buildKey(29 + i, false, context, i + 5),
_buildKey(31 + i, false, context, i + 7),
_buildKey(33 + i, false, context, i + 9),
_buildKey(35 + i, false, context, i + 11),
],
),

I have another provider that changes the scale (set of notes to play on the keyboard) and I watch in my build widget for a change.

This is the call :

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

```
final ScaleProvider scaleProvider = context.watch<ScaleProvider>();
Scale? myScale = scaleProvider.getScale();

playScale(myScale!, context);
```

So I need to have a while loop that play notes one at the time in a function and calls the read for changing each note on the keyboard.

Future playScale(Scale scale, BuildContext context) async {

int currentIndex = 0;

while (_buttonPressPlay) {

```
if(currentIndex == scale.scaleLenght! - 1)
{
  currentIndex = 0;
}
else
{
  currentIndex++;
}

Note note = scale!.notes!.elementAt(currentIndex);

if (context.mounted)
{
  await context.read<PianoKeysProvider>().playNoteFromIndex(note.positionX, note.positionY);
}

await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 500));
```

}
}

I got an exception : setState() or markNeedsBuild called during build

I tried to use future.delayed (the application stop being asynchrone or freeze at context.watch) or context.monted but same exception.
Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () {

```
final ScaleProvider scaleProvider = context.watch<ScaleProvider>();
Scale? myScale = scaleProvider.getScale();
playScale(myScale!, context);
```

}
});

Where I should go from there ? Any thoughts ? Thank you so much (first time posting on Stack Overflow :D )!

Answer (score 0):

you can use `WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback()` to make sure that `setState()` or `notifyListeners()` will not be called during build

```
WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
  setState(() {});
  notifyListeners();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I looks like everytime the rebuild is done, the widgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallBack is being called. So, it breaks the loop.

Comment: WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
        // Notify listeners after the frame is built
          context.read<PianoKeysProvider>().playNoteFromIndex(0,43);
    });

Comment: It was the solution indeed thanks ! I used a global variable bool, to set to true or false depending of the context and now, there's no async problems.  bool _isBuilding = true;       WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
      _isBuilding = false;
    });